# vue ui error type server.installSubscriptionHandlers is not a function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, yarn-v2

When I use the vue ui command, I get the following error : TypeError: server.installSubscriptionHandlers is not a function

I use yarn and I don't intend to use npm.

`PS C:\Users\Lenovo\Desktop\Learnvue\master> vue ui   Starting GUI... Persisted queries are enabled and are using an unbounded cache. Your server is vulnerable to denial of service attacks via memory exhaustion. Set`cache: "bounded" `or persistedQueries: false` in your ApolloServer constructor, or see https://go.apollo.dev/s/cache-backends for other alternatives.
ERROR  TypeError: server.installSubscriptionHandlers is not a function
TypeError: server.installSubscriptionHandlers is not a function
at module.exports (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules@vue\cli-ui\graphql-server.js:165:10)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async ui (C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules@vue\cli\lib\ui.js:71:26)`

yarn version : 1.22.19
vue version : @vue/cli 5.0.7

Answer (score 0):

#### I had the same issue. It has to do with the old CLI. Make sure you upgrade to the latest vue.

Warning regarding Previous Versions

The package name changed from vue-cli to @vue/cli. If you have the previous vue-cli (1.x or 2.x) package installed globally, you need to uninstall it first with npm uninstall vue-cli -g or yarn global remove vue-cli.

```
npm update -g @vue/cli
```

OR

```
yarn global upgrade --latest @vue/cli
```